# What's this box in steam locomotives?

Tags: rail, steam

In the past few weeks I've seen several European steam locomotives in museums. I noticed several of them have a box in the driver's cabin, similar to the one in the picture I've attached. Several cables or tubes leave this box in a circular arrangement and I wonder what this box is doing. So, what is it?

[image: Box in steam locomotive]

(Engineering.SE seems to be the best fit for this question; if there's a better one, please let me know.)

Comment: It is probably a lubrication system for some of the mechanisms - others have oil baths or oil glasses which need topping up before use.

Comment: If you're still touring museums, show that picture to an attendant and ask.  If you get hooked up with an enthusiast, you may get more information than you really wanted!

Comment: Fuel pump for an oil burner????

Comment: This is a steamer.  It has only one combustion chamber which burns constantly (unlike a diesel).  Fuel pump unlikely.  (Even if it were a non-common-rail diesel, the fuel pump would be closer to the cylinder, and it would be timed from the crankshaft.)

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but that looks like a pressure feed for the boiler. Considering it is a machine that builds water pressure, this is probably the distribution point into the burner of the water to be converted into steam.